# BASE64 to bitmap

Tags: kotlin

I am trying to decode base64 string type image to bitmap but my android studio is not recognizing "decode" method in

```
val imageBytes = Base64.decode(string, 0)
val image = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(imageBytes, 0, imageBytes.size)
```

Comment: what library are you using for Base64 decoding? Apache Commons Codec has a `Base64` class but it has no `decode` method. Same goes for Java 8

Answer (score 2):

This could caused by importing the wrong class. It might be that Android Studio is interpreting that as `java.util.Base64` which has no `decode` method. Instead, you want to use the `Base64` class declared in `android.util`. Try using a fully qualified reference to make sure the IDE selects the right one

```
val encodedImage: String
val imageBytes = android.util.Base64.decode(encodedImage, 0)
```